# Asymmetric Gaussian Filter - Different Size and STD for Horizontal and Vertical Filters

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, convolution, gaussian

I now want to use **asymmetric Gaussian filter** kernel to smooth an image using MATLAB, because I don't want the equal smoothness in vertical and horizontal(**with different size of Gaussian mode and different  standard deviation**). But I cannot find a system function to do this job. It seems that the function `fspecial()` doesn't support this.

So, how can I implement this filter?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply horizontal and vertical filtering **separately**.

```
v = fspecial( 'gaussian', [11 1], 5 ); % vertical filter
h = fspecial( 'gaussian', [1 5], 2 ); % horizontal
img = imfilter( imfilter( img, h, 'symmetric' ), v, 'symmetric' );
```

Moreover, you can "compose" the two filters using an outer product

```
f = v * h; % this is NOT a dot product - this returns a matrix!
img = imfilter( img, f, 'symmetric' );
```

PS
if you are looking for a directional filtering, you might want to consider `fspecial('motion'...)`

Comment: `f = v * h;` is a more elegant solution `imfilter` is an expensive operation. I do not want to have two.

Comment: Note that 'guassian' should be 'gaussian' - apparently an edit must be 6 characters for me to fix it.

Comment: 'symmteric' should also be 'symmetric', sorry for my delay in noticing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `fspecial` with a twist, for example:

```
 H= fspecial('gaussian',15,2) ;
 H2=imresize(H,[1.5*size(H,1) size(H,2)]);
 Img=conv2(Img,H2,'same');
```

Using `imresize` on the filter allows to control the x vs y axis asymmetry of the gaussian. Similarly you can use any type of image transformation (see `imtransform`) you can imagine to skew stretch etc...

Comment: it's not the same, it depends that the OP wants to do... I just demonstrated one way...

Answer (score 3):

You can approximate a Gaussian filter by applying a Box filter multiple times. Since the Gaussian is separable, you can do this separately in both dimensions. A box filter in one dimension is a simple average over a linear segment of pixels. I don't know anything about matlab but I assume it can do this. If matlab can do rectangular filters you wouldn't even need to separate it.

For more details about approximating a Gaussian see http://nghiaho.com/?p=1159

Answer (score 0):

You can use MATLAB's `conv2()` function which support Separable Filters and also faster than `imfilter()`.

So it would be something like:

```matlab
v = fspecial( 'gaussian', [11 1], 5 ); % vertical filter
h = fspecial( 'gaussian', [1 5], 2 ); % horizontal
mO = conv2(v, h, mI);
```

Where `mI` is the input image and `mO` is the output.